# Is it possible to concatenate strings with large Chars(UTF32String) in Julia-lang?

Tags: julia, utf-32

Construct UTF32String (b,c), where b contains large value:

```
using LegacyStrings
a=Char(69058047)
b=UTF32String(a)
c=UTF32String("")
```

Now concatenate b and c into d:

```
d=b*c
```

Read b,c,d respectively. b retained its value, but d is forcibly converted below 2^16, typed UTF8String, with its value being lost?

```
julia> typeof(d)
UTF8String

julia> typeof(b)
UTF32String

julia> typeof(c)
UTF32String

julia> D=Int(Char(d[1]))
65533

julia> B=Int(Char(b[1]))
69058047
```

Doing this on Julia 0.4 and 0.6 yielded the same result. Is it possible to get a work around to operate on strings with large Chars?

Comment: That is not even a valid Unicode code point.  Is there some reason you are trying to operate on invalid strings?

Comment: Humm, encryption. I was curious if all 2^32 Chars can be used. Besides, I wonder whether this could be the reason a program parsing texts exhibited bugs on a few files? (A similar bug was solved when I changed UTF16String to UTF32String.)

Comment: If you are not really using valid text data, you should be using something like a `Vector{UInt32}` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to save array to a file with little space? Maybe 1.5* or even 2* as much as string text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there is a change in char representation coming in 0.7 the answer to the question depends on version of Julia you use.

#### Julia 0.7

If you want to use Julia 0.7 (and probably this is what you should be targeting as in the long run you have to switch to it anyway) you will get:

```
julia> a=Char(69058047)
ERROR: Base.CodePointError(0x041dbdff)
Stacktrace:
 [1] code_point_err(::UInt32) at .\char.jl:10
 [2] Type at .\char.jl:42 [inlined]
 [3] Char(::Int64) at .\boot.jl:682
 [4] top-level scope
```

In short - you will not be allowed to create it at all.

It is important to know that the border value for throwing conversion error is `0x001fffff` although it is invalid (maximum valid Unicode is `0x0010ffff`).
This is a catch that you simply have to remember in 0.7.

The reason is that values up to `0x001fffff` can be mapped to UTF-8, although some of those UTF-8 representations are invalid (larger values are impossible to map).

#### Julia 0.6.2

Here you can create `a`, `b`, and `c`, but the problem is that `b*c` is equivalent to `string(b, c)` (thus it will convert it to `String` in the end no mater what type you pass to it as an argument) and in the end, if you dig deep enough this will call `write(s::IO, ch::Char)`, witch `ch` equal to `a`, and if you look at the definition of this method you will see that for `a` it will produce `'\ufffd'` - and this is what you get.

Julia 0.6.2 will emit `'\ufffd'` for all invalid Unicode, i.e. any larger than `0x0010ffff`.

Comment: Maybe 266665 Chars are enough. The remaining thing that puzzles me is that log(2, 266665) == 18? Was there a reason to not using the remaining (32-18) bits?

Comment: Where did you take `266665`? In Julia 0.7 you can map `2097151` characters, although there are only `1114111` valid Unicode characters. The reason is that UTF-8 character is encoded as `11110xxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx10xxxxxx` (I simplify it a bit, for details look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), where `x` is either 0 or 1. As you have 21 `x`s you can map up to `2^21=2097152` characters in Julia 0.7. Is this clear now?